# How to extend ootb class from backoffice extension?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

How to extend ootb class (class exist inside jar) from backoffice extension from my the class of my custom extension.

steps I have followed :

1) created my class inside customextension -> backoffice/src folder 2) Done bean configuration xxxspring.xml

Still my class is calling (Not any getting error while build or server start)

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: What is the OOTB class you are extending?

Comment: I am extending 'UserRoleChooserWidgetController' .

Comment: error ---/webroot/WEB-INF/lib/cockpitadmin-6.6.0.1-RC5.jar!/metainfo/zk-label_en.properties
ERROR [hybrisHTTP2] [Property] Failed to assign [label=                                                         ${labels.login.singlesignon.label}              SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [zkLoader] in context with path [/backoffice] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.getAttachedUiEngine(AbstractComponent.java:376)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the comments and from the steps you took, that is not enough when you're extending a widget controller.

[Here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/5c9ea0c629214e42b727bf08800d8dfa/1905/en-US/8bda5dec866910148593fca2c20f6a0e.html#loio8bda5dec866910148593fca2c20f6a0e) is a good tutorial for extending widgets and an important step here is to define the **new** controller in widget's *definition.xml*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget-definition extends="the widget path here"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.hybris.com/schema/cockpitng/widget-definition.xsd">

...
   <controller class="your new controller path" />
...
</widget-definition>
```

**PS:** please note that the `<widget-definition>` tag doesn't contain any *id* attribute, only an *extends*. In this way you can override the original widget definition.

Comment: Actually I need the current login user details of backoffice users.

Comment: Ok, but what I told you had nothing to do with what you said.